# Extracting a word from a string starting with a particular word till the end

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I need to extract a particular attribute from an HTML element. 
This is an SVG element and it has clip-path as an attribute. I need to replace the clip-path that comes with the html with my custom clip-path. How can i do that.

My outer HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" border="0" width="1303" height="347"  role="presentation" style="display: block;">
        <clipPath clip-rule="nonzero" id="ac_clip_1">
            <path data-ac-wrapper-id="26" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M 96 10 L 1283 10 1283 295 96 295 96 10 Z"></path>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath clip-rule="nonzero" id="ac_clip_2">
            <path data-ac-wrapper-id="28" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M 96 10 L 1283 10 1283 295 96 295 96 10 Z"></path>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath clip-rule="nonzero" id="ac_clip_3">
            <path data-ac-wrapper-id="30" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M 96 10 L 1283 10 1283 295 96 295 96 10 Z"></path>
        </clipPath>

        <g data-ac-wrapper-id="23">
            <path data-ac-wrapper-id="24" fill="transparent" stroke="none" d="M 0 0 L 1303 0 1303 0 1303 347 1303 347 0 347 0 347 0 0 0 0 Z">
            </path>
        </g>
        <path id="68" clip-path="url(file:///C:/Users/user1/Desktop/svg.html#ac_clip_1)" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 0,0"></path>
        <path id="69" clip-path="url(file:///C:/Users/user1/Desktop/svg.html#ac_clip_2)" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 0,0"></path>
        ....
    </svg>
</div>
```

I want to replace `clip-path="url(file:///C:/Users/user1/Desktop/svg.html#ac_clip_1/2/3...)` from the entire HTML with `clip-path="url(#ac_clip_1/2/3..)`

Any heads up will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```js
/*
Collect all <path>s -- that have the [clip-path] attribute that
has the value of "url" anywhere within it -- into a NodeList.
*/
var paths = document.querySelectorAll('path[clip-path*=url]');

/*
On each loop through the NodeList...
...use .setAttributeNS() to change the value of [clip-path]
attribute...
...and modify the value by incrementing the last char by index +1
*/
for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
  paths[i].setAttributeNS(null, 'clip-path', `url(#ac_clip_${(i + 1)})`);
  console.log(`path#${paths[i].id}[clip-path="${ paths[i].getAttributeNS(null, 'clip-path')}"]`);
}
```

```html
<p>Use Developer Tools to verify new [clip-path] values.</p>
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" border="0" width="1303" height="347" role="presentation" style="display: block;">
        <clipPath clip-rule="nonzero" id="ac_clip_1">
            <path data-ac-wrapper-id="26" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M 96 10 L 1283 10 1283 295 96 295 96 10 Z"></path>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath clip-rule="nonzero" id="ac_clip_2">
            <path data-ac-wrapper-id="28" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M 96 10 L 1283 10 1283 295 96 295 96 10 Z"></path>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath clip-rule="nonzero" id="ac_clip_3">
            <path data-ac-wrapper-id="30" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M 96 10 L 1283 10 1283 295 96 295 96 10 Z"></path>
        </clipPath>

        <g data-ac-wrapper-id="23">
            <path data-ac-wrapper-id="24" fill="transparent" stroke="none" d="M 0 0 L 1303 0 1303 0 1303 347 1303 347 0 347 0 347 0 0 0 0 Z">
            </path>
        </g>
        <path id="68" clip-path="url(file:///C:/Users/user1/Desktop/svg.html#ac_clip_1)" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 0,0"></path>
        <path id="69" clip-path="url(file:///C:/Users/user1/Desktop/svg.html#ac_clip_2)" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 0,0"></path>   
        <path id="70" clip-path="url(file:///C:/Users/user1/Desktop/svg.html#ac_clip_3)" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 0,0"></path>
 
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the elements with the attribute, do `.querySelectorAll('[clip-path]')` on the containing element.

Then loop over all the elements and do `.replace(/^.*#/, '#')` on all the clip-path attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [setAttribute](http://setAttribute()) on the DOM.

### getElementById

We can use `getElementById` if you want to do this on path's with a specific id.

```
document.getElementById("68").setAttribute("clip-path", "url(#ac_clip_1/2/3..)");
```

### getElementsByTagName

A more elegant solution would be to use `getElementsByTagName` to replace them all in case your replacement string is not unique. If your clip-paths have incremental id's you can use the index variable provided in the foreach to manipulate the replacement URL accordingly.

```
var allPaths = document.getElementsByTagName("path");
allPaths.forEach(function(element, index){
    element.setAttribute("clip-path", "url(#ac_clip_1/2/3..)");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Arjan. but it may not actually be necessary for the tag to only appear in the 'path' of the SVG, it may occur directly on the <g> tag as well. Apologies as it may not be clear from my code example.

Comment: My bad, I thought it was only for the path element.